# Jquery, .val() não pega o texto do input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu tenho um seguinte código:

**INPUT**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">                                                                
        <div class="col-sm-3">                                                                      
            <div class="form-group input-group">
                <input id="contact-input" type="text" id="search" class="form-control input-search-doc" placeholder="Documento" required>
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-search-doc" type="button">
                    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                </button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div><!-- <div class="col-sm-3"> -->                                                                                           
    </div><!-- <div class="form-group"> -->
</div><!-- <div class="row"> -->
```

**AJAX**

```
$(".btn-search-doc").on("click",function(){
    var title = $(this).find('input.input-search-doc').val();
    alert(title);   
    $("#result").html("<img src='ajax-loader.gif'/>");

    $.ajax({
        type:"post",
        url:"../connect/post/select.php",
        data:"title="+title,
        success:function(data){
            $("#result").html(data);
            $("#search").val("");
         }
      });

});
```

Ele deveria pegar o texto dentro do input e enviar via Ajax para meu select, mas ele não consegue pegar o texto dentro do input **"input-search-doc"**, sempre retorna para mim no var_dump : *string 'undefined' (length=9)*

Alguém tem uma ideia porque ele não está pegando valor nenhum?

Comment: Seu seletor deveria ser assim:   var title = $('.input-search-doc').val();  não faz sentido nenhum usar o this neste caso, só faria se fosse um form, e você fosse dar um submit

Comment: Obrigado era isso mesmo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplesmente use:

```
$('#contact-input').val();
```

Ou

```
$('.input-search-doc').val();
```

Comment: Para pegar um componente passando o ID do controle no seletor, utilize "#" como no exemplo do @Jonathan. Nada mais.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, tudo bem?

Acredito que o problema está quando você instancia a variável 'title':

```js
$(".btn-search-doc").on("click",function(){
    var title = $(this).parents('.input-group').find('input.input-search-doc').val();
    alert(title);   

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">                                                                
        <div class="col-sm-3">                                                                      
            <div class="form-group input-group">
                <input id="contact-input" type="text" id="search" class="form-control input-search-doc" placeholder="Documento" required>
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-search-doc" type="button">
                    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                </button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div><!-- <div class="col-sm-3"> -->                                                                                           
    </div><!-- <div class="form-group"> -->
</div><!-- <div class="row"> -->
```

Para vc manter o contexto onde está englobado seu botão utilizando o $(this), é necessário utilizar o ".parents('.input-group')" para mudar o contexto do botão para o div que contém o botão e o campo de entrada, para somente então utilizar o ".find()" para achar o campo.

Ou

Já que você está definindo um identificador único pro input, vc poderia buscar o mesmo assim: $('#contact-input').